# XBOX 360 not booting up after update corrupted files

Tags: xbox-360

So I have an XBOX 360 slim that I don't update all the time, I don't have internet where I live, so I have to update it at friend's houses. (Why do you hate poor people, Microsoft?) Someone gave me Batman Arkham Origins for Christmas, but of course to play it I had to update the console. I did that and my profile was corrupted. I tried to delete the corrupted files and it froze up on me, so I tried powering it down. Now it literally will do nothing. It makes that bing noise when I push Eject or Power, but **no** light comes on. It just bings and sits there.  Any thoughts? I mean other than "buy a new one" because that isn't going to happen unless gold crapping mole men from Titan set up shop in my back yard.

Comment: just to let you know, any game release for the 360 comes with the system update you need for that game, so if you got a 360 and for years never updated then suddenly got Assassin's Creed Black Flag, it will prompt you to run the update which is included, you never need the internet to update unless you was playing online

Comment: That's very helpful, but doesn't really help me now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Boot up the Xbox and try holding "left trigger and Y" till the Xbox finishes booting up(controller plugged in). This will reset your display setting and may help. Please also try this... http://www.xbox.com/en-AU/Support/UpdateSteps and finally if you hold A while booting up, this may wipe your update cache. Call Microsoft.

Comment: Remove the HDD?

Comment: Comments are for comments or informational suggestions, not answers @user65974.

Comment: M$ hates poor people because they aren't profitable.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking your hard drive out and to your friends house. When you do that see if the Xbox will boot up, then take a flash drive and move the games and stuff you want to keep over to it and wipe your hard drive. If the Xbox doesn't boot up the take it to a shop and have them look at it.